# how to make .exe file in python with no system messages

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Now I'm coding an automatic e-mail transmission program for the company.

I need to see the progress by print("something"), but now the system message(due to base64 encoding) is printed in the middle,
so I must be attached "2> nul" after execution code to see only the print content I want.

The problem is, when I make this code an .exe file by "pyinstaller",
I don't know how to operate a function like 2> nul in this case.

(I tried to create the .bat file, but failed because the python file was in the Public Network folder.)

If anyone knows, please let me know.
I hope my English was easy to understand.

Thank you.

Comment: I dont think you meant to say *no stdout*. Stdout is the file stream that take user input.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i just fixed it